# D3 V4 setting initial zoom level

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've just started using D3 V4 and I'm having trouble getting a pan and zoom function working. The problem is that I want the initial scale value to be something over than 1 so I set this using

```
zoom.scaleTo(svg, 2);
```

However as soon as I pan or zoom the scale resets back to 1.

Here's an example of this behavior on JSFiddle, what am I doing wrong?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/skgktrcu/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600)
    .attr("height", 600)
  .call(zoom)
  .append("g");
```

You are assigning the group element instead of the svg element to the variable `svg`.

The `zoom` is correctly applied to the svg element, but then when you call `zoom.scaleTo(svg, 2)` you are zooming the group element, not the svg element.

This can be fixed by first creating and assigning the svg element to the `svg` variable and only then creating and assigning the group element.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 600)
    .attr("height", 600)
    .call(zoom);

var mainContainer = svg.append("g");
```

Here's the fixed JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/skgktrcu/2/

Comment: Damn can't believe it was so simple, thanks for that

Comment: If this answer fixed your problem, please accept it instead of upvoting it. Thanks! http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Comment: Oops sorry new to this

Comment: It's ok. We've all been there. Welcome to StackOverflow! :)

Comment: Thanks, plus1, but how do you get the current zoom level since `zoom.scale()` is no more?